# Double Integral region bounded by

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image: Description of Problem]

I went with answer B. I believe that double integral i achieves the correct magnitude but does not get the sign correct. That is I think instead of 1 to 1-x it should be 1-x to 1.

I was hoping that someone could verify this for me, because I'm having some doubts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integral (i) is not correct:  for $x \in [0,2]$, $1 \ge 1-x$, thus the value of this integral is negated relative to the desired integral.  Integral (ii) is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and explanation